# Use string from App.Resources as the value for a ResourceDictionary's Source property {WPF}

Tags: c#, wpf, path, resourcedictionary

I wanted to implement multiple languages in my application without using a Resources file (`*.resx`), and I wanted to use a separate ResourceDictionary for this, `Text/en-US.xaml`. Since I wanted the language to update all at once, I made each `Window`, `Page`, *etc.* to set their `Resources` property to a `ResourceDictionary`, whose source is the path of the language file.

First, I tried setting the container's `Resources` property to a `ResourceDictionary`, and the `Source` property of that resource dictionary used the curly brace resource mechanism, like this:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="{DynamicResource AppLangPath}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

However, at Line 4 of that code, the `Source` property has the error underline, and the name `AppLangPath` doesn't even appear in IntelliSense. However, I was expecting there to be no underline, and for the name to appear in IntelliSense, and for the strings located in `en-US.xaml` to be shown in IntelliSense too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot set the `Source` property of a `ResourceDictionary` using the `DynamicResource` markup extension in XAML because it's not a dependency property.

To switch language you should programmatically replace one `ResourceDictionary` with another one, e.g.:

```
this.Resources.Clear(); //this refers to the window
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("Text/sv-SE.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
});
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I think I can also use events to switch the language app-wide.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate ResourceDictionary file "AppResources.xaml", you can define the "AppLangPath" property as follows:

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <sys:String x:Key="AppLangPath">/Text/en-US.xaml</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, in your window or page XAML, you can reference the "AppLangPath" property using the curly brace syntax:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="{DynamicResource AppLangPath}" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code I currently have (although instead of using a separate `AppResources.xaml` for this, I just put it in `Application.Resources`)